# how to add background tasks in heroku for laravel

Tags: laravel, heroku

I want to setup background screen task in heroku

currently am using this below command but it stops after every 24 hours how can I attach it to background that run forever and restart with each deployment

`heroku run:detached php artisan queue:work`

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile):

```
worker: php artisan queue:work
```

#### Procfile:

Heroku apps include a Procfile that specifies the commands that are executed by the app on startup. You can use a Procfile to declare a variety of process types, including:

- Your app’s web server
- **Multiple types of worker processes**
- A singleton process, such as a clock
- Tasks to run before a new release is deployed

Comment: Procfile work for me 

web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
worker: php artisan fail:label

below command if worker did not start 

heroku ps:scale worker=1

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler takes quite a bit of work to get it working on Heroku. What we've done in several projects is instead to use the Heroku Scheduler addon (under resources in Heroku backend)

[image]

Then you can add your artisan commands in a cronjob, that fires with the interval you like. It's really simple and saves you so much hassle!
[image]

Comment: Hi, 
I need task to monitor every time not with schedule time
e.g. email background process that checks request every time in a queue, scheduler is not acceptable in my case .

Comment: Please, note that the Heroku Scheduler only run at least every 10 minutes.